# Running executable in another terminal other than cmd C#

Tags: c#-4.0, batch-file, process, cmd

I have a question on how to make process work around in C#.

Suppose I write a program or an executable A.exe, which needs to run in another terminal Environment other than cmd. Manually, I could start that terminal, and then locate my A.exe, then execute. But if we want to write program to automatically start that terminal and ran A.exe, how could we do that.

To be more specific, A.exe may need tools or have dependencies provided by the other terminal. That's why we need to open that terminal first, and inside that terminal environment to run A.exe.

Any suggestions on how to write programs or batch to open that terminal and run A.exe in that terminal? Or there is any other way to implement?

Thanks much!

Comment: provide some more detail. What is "another terminal environment" you mean a different shell? which shell? how do you invoke it? does it provide a way to pass commands to it?

Comment: Yes, yes, a different shell which may have totally different environment. By looking at its property, it provides its env.cmd in Target. I can invoke it manually opening it. Just do not how to write code to start it and run some other processes inside that shell.

Comment: so, it uses the same command interpreter, cmd.exe, right?

Answer (score 0):

you may just start both the .BAT setting the appropiate environment and then your program in a single .BAT file

```
CALL ENV.BAT
A.EXE
```

Comment: The Problem Solved. We could first open the other terminal environment and then append & batchfiles in order to run batch files in that environment.